# Why is it that the existing APIs used with Classic Load Balancer cannot be used with Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

AWS documentation mentions 'Application Load Balancers require a new set of APIs'. Why is it that the existing APIs used with Classic Load Balancer cannot be used with Application Load Balancer?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Classic Load Balancers (v1 - old generation 2009) and Application Load Balancers (v2 - new generation 2016) is that ALBs have a port mapping feature to redirect to a dynamic port. In Comparison we would need to create one CLB per application.

Overall CLBs are deprecated and you use ALBs for HTTP/HTTPS and Websockets and Network Load Balancers for TCP.

Coming to your question. On ALBs you map certain paths (like an API endpoint) to a target group (e.g. EC2 instances). Within those instances you could trigger a lambda or whatever to execute your logic. This logic can stay the same as it is when you used it with a CLB.

Comment: Application Load Balancers require a new set of APIs - why is that?

Comment: This probably refers to the different APIs to use ALBs and CLBs. In the docs you can see the two different API references for the two different APIs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/index.html